# ImportError: No module named lxml python 3.4.4 on Win 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, lxml, importerror

I am running Python 3.4.4 on Windows 7 machine.

```
from lxml import html
```

I keep getting this error: `"ImportError: No module named lxml"`
However, I have installed the module numerous times, with the following attempted PIP commands within the Python34\Scripts folder to no avail.

```
pip install lxml == 3.4.4.
pip install lxml
```

Noticed this error as well, when I attempt to install `lxml`. However, when I attempt to find that file in the folder, the folder does not exist.

http://www.mattcole.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Capture.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can easily locate the installation path(in my case: C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages), copy the lxml folder and paste it inside your project directory's lib folder (in my case:PycharmProjects\pjt_name\venv\Lib\site-packages.

Everything should work fine now!